# Two URL's in one HTML Button. Is it possible?

Tags: html, redirect, button, web, arduino

i'm currently developing a site with arduino project which is WEB SWITCH.

I got codes like this..

```
 //Prints the ON Buttons
client.print("<td>");
//client.print(buttonText[var]);
client.print("<INPUT TYPE=\"button\" VALUE=\"ON ");
//client.print(buttonText[var]);
client.print("\" onClick=\"parent.location='/?H");
client.print(var);
client.print("'\"></td>\n");

//Prints the OFF Buttons 
client.print(" <td><INPUT TYPE=\"button\" VALUE=\"OFF");
//client.print(var);
client.print("\" onClick=\"parent.location='/?L");
client.print(var);
client.print("'\"></td>\n");
```

It prints ON and OFF button in my site.
whenever i click those buttons..
for example, i clicked on.. the location will be "192.168.0.200/?Hvar"
after visiting that location i want it to instantly redirect to "192.168.0.200/"
is it possible?

Please help me.

Comment: How about having the HTML served by 192.168.0.200/?Hvar redirect to 192.168.0.200?

Comment: Any code ideas? i actually have low knowledge in html codings. please help me

Comment: I don't. But try looking at this: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html

Comment: I already saw that code. I also tried it. But it always refresh my page without pushing the buttons, although i put it on the part of the button code, it always refresh my page.. 

i want to redirect just when the button is being click.